# Dividir alto fijo entre hijos

Tags: html, css, web, diseño

Tengo un `div` (llamemoslo X) que ocupa un 85% de la pantalla y necesito que dentro de ese `div` se puedan agregar otros divs, algunos contienen texto, otros imágenes y otros videos. Cada hijo ocupa un 100% del ancho del padre, pero el alto del padre se distribuye entre los `div` hijo que tenga (dándoles la misma cantidad de espacio a cada uno, por más que uno solo necesite 10 píxeles). ¿Alguna sugerencia de como llevarlo a cabo?

El código siguiente funciona sin imágenes, pero las imagenes rompen el contenedor flex saliéndose por fuera, ¿alguna idea?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    #container {
      width: 85%;
      height: 85%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .elem {
      border: 1px solid #BBBB1199;
      flex-basis: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="image elem">
      <img src="https://www.hd-wallpapersdownload.com/script/bulk-upload/lion-big-wallpapers.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="elem">TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué debería ocurrir cuando la imagen (o el contenido del `div`) ocupe más del alto que le corresponde?

Answer (score 0):

Que todos los `div` hijos tengan la misma altura, lo tienes ya hecho con flexbox y funciona correctamente. El problema es cuando el contenido ocupa más de la cuenta.

Para esos casos podrías añadirle un `overflow: hidden` a los `div` hijos para que las imágenes/video/contenido no *rompan* el tamaño de su contenedor. Así todos los `div` con clase `elem` tendrán la misma altura.

El problema ahora es que cuando una imagen (o un video) es muy grande, se ve cortada. Si quieres que se vea completa, podrías añadirle `height: 100%` para que se ajuste al tamaño del `div` que la contiene.

Aquí puedes ver tu código sólo con esos dos cambios. Ahora los `div` ocupan lo mismo y la imagen del león se ajusta al tamaño de su contenedor:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    #container {
      width: 85%;
      height: 85%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .elem {
      border: 1px solid #BBBB1199;
      flex-basis: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .elem img {
      max-height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="image elem">
      <img src="https://www.hd-wallpapersdownload.com/script/bulk-upload/lion-big-wallpapers.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="elem">TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```